# Error Database schema could not be retrieved for this connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Edit: if you are downvoting can you at least tell me what Im missing so I can improve my question?

I have a website which uses a SQL Server database. It works fine when building both debug and release.

But if I add a new `SqlDataSource` to my project and try to configure it in design view, I get this error:

> Database scheme could not be retrieved for this connection. Please make sure the connection settings are correct and that the database is online.
>
> Failed to retrieve data for this request.
>   Failed to connect to server---------.
>   Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'.

Even if I configure the connection string with the connection-guide, test the connection and save, it fails afterwards when trying to configure the datasource.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=SERVER\SQLEXPRESS,61180;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;
```

So to clarify: The connection string works fine when running the website in both debug and release, and if I connect using SQL Server Management Studio, but the only place it doesn't work is when I try to configure the datasource in design view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found out that I had to put `Persist Security Info=True;` into the connectionstring to get it to work.

First time in my 10+ years of programming that I encountered this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem also since upgrading to VS2017, and you pointed me in the right direction. I found that I also had to put the "Persist Security Info=True" after the Data Source and before the User ID.  It wouldn't work putting it at the end for some reason.